ModuleNotFoundError: No module named scipy.special._cdflib with SciPy-1.13.0
platform:windows server 2019
python:3.12.2
scipy:1.13.0
When I upgraded scipy from 1.12 to 1.13 there was No module named scipy.special._cdflib.This doesn't happen when I use 1.12.0.
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "src\predict.py", line 14, in <module> 
    from src.utils.calc_utils import *
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "src\utils\calc_utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 167, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\interpolate\_interpolate.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "scipy\special\__init__.py", line 777, in <module>
  File "scipy\\special\\_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.special._cdflib'


How to solve this problem? Why does this problem occur?

Are you trying to import scipy.special._cdflib, or are you trying to import something else, which then imports cdflib? If it's the latter, can you provide a traceback?

Appenrently this is a known issue in pyinstaller, look at which version you have. In the changelog it states

Update scipy.special._ufuncs hook for compatibility with SciPy 1.13.0 (add scipy.special._cdflib to hidden imports). (#8394)

So using version 6.6.0 of pyinstaller might work

_cdflib is private, as indicated by the leading underscore. It has been rewritten in Cython, so the specifics of the private interface may have changed dramatically. However, the public interface to each function has remained the same, so import what you need from the public scipy.special namespace.
That said, import scipy.special._cdflib still works in 1.13.0, so you'd need to provide code to reproduce the problem in your question if you still need help.

I didn't use it that way, I use like this  from scipy.interpolate import interp1d and then use pyinstall pack to exe file. This error occurs when I use this exe file

I encountered the same problem as you after I upgraded scipy from 1.11.4 to 1.13.0. The problem was solved after I kept scipy at 1.11.4. So I would recommend not upgrading it for now if previously your programme was working fine.
